# How to animate hiding/showing of tab bar?

Tags: react-navigation

Using react-navigation v3.

How to animate the hiding/showing of the `createMaterialTabNavigator` within a React Native app?

It currently looks like this, but notice the sudden appearance of the tab bar... I would like it to be smoother, sliding in from/to the bottom.

[image: Sample]

I have found various docs that animate the tab bar items, but not the tab bar itself.

Comment: did you find any solution for it?

Comment: no, I never found a solution for this.

Comment: I am actually trying to implementing this. Let's see what happens.

Comment: Let me know how that goes!

Comment: of course......